# How to programatically change views in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, storyboard

In Xcode 4.5 you can change views from a segue, But I want to programatically change views in Mainstoryboard. I Know in Xib. we use this method:

```
SecondViewController *Second = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
[self presentModalViewController:Second animated:YES];
```

I want to change the view when the user clicks done in the textfield (This code detects if user clicks done):

```
-(IBAction)hidekeyboard {

    [sender resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative to segueing is to instantiate the viewController from the storyboard.

First you assign a Storyboard ID to the viewController in the storyboard.

[image]

Then you instantiate that viewController, and present it.

```
MBTagEditorViewController *tagEditor = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"TagEditor"];
[self presentModalViewController:tagEditor animated:YES];
```

Comment: Code is Great except I am getting an error presentModalViewController is depreciated in iOS 6

Answer (score 3):

You create a segue in your storyboard that goes from the view that has the text field in question and goes to your `SecondViewController`.  You have to assign an identifier to it (also in the storyboard, click on the line connecting the two view controllers), let's call it "segueToSecondViewController".  Then, you can manually call the segue using:

```
[self.storyboard performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segueToSecondViewController" sender:self];
```